# VS Code Remote-Containers: Open Repository in Container

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

Not sure this is the right forum for my question, but here it goes. I'm having problems opening my azure-devops repo in a container using vs code (F1 -> Remote-Containers: Open Repository in Container). The operation fails with the following message:

[image]

What am I missing? I can clone the repo just fine from the terminal:

```
piotr@EMEA00304 Downloads % git clone https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole
Cloning into 'piotr-helloworldconsole'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: We noticed you're using an older version of Git. For the best experience, upgrade to a newer version.
remote: Found 4 objects to send. (71 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (4/4), done.
piotr@EMEA00304 Downloads % cd piotr-helloworldconsole 
piotr@EMEA00304 piotr-helloworldconsole % ls
HelloWorldConsole.csproj    Program.cs
```

Do I need to configure vs code with my credentials somehow?

I'm sorry if this is obvious, but could not find anything in the documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_container-tips

The version of vs code I use is `1.43.2`.

---

UPDATE:

I double checked and I am using the same URL in terminal and in vs code, the one given by the azure-devops ui:

`https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole`

[image]

This is the output I get in vs code:

```
[0 ms] Start: Resolving remote
[4 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[32 ms] Start: Run: docker build -f /Users/piotr/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.106.0/scripts/volumeBootstrap.Dockerfile -t vsc-volume-bootstrap /Users/piotr/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.106.0/scripts
[140 ms] Sending build context to Docker daemon   7.68kB
[209 ms] Step 1/2 : FROM alpine:3.11.2
[210 ms]  ---> cc0abc535e36
Step 2/2 : RUN apk add --no-cache       nodejs  git     openssh-client  docker-cli      ;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d89d8b8c3615
[210 ms] Successfully built d89d8b8c3615
[214 ms] Successfully tagged vsc-volume-bootstrap:latest
[216 ms] Cloning Github repository: _git/piotr-helloworldconsole.git into /workspaces/piotr-helloworldconsole

[217 ms] Start: Run: docker run -d --mount src=vsc-remote-containers,dst=/workspaces,type=volume,volume-driver=local -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock vsc-volume-bootstrap sleep infinity
[592 ms] Start: Run: docker exec -i -u root 1092b2cb7af09d3f9c9648f243f2279ac7ad895e215d859be57542c9f3d87f0e /bin/sh
[596 ms] Start: Launching Remote-Containers helper.
[598 ms] Start: Run in container: command -v git >/dev/null 2>&1 && git config --global credential.helper '!f() { node /tmp/vscode-remote-containers-d357f963b0fea8b37100746ad6d1376e6226b019.js $*; }; f' || true
[737 ms] 
[737 ms] 
[737 ms] Start: Run in container: cat <<'EOF-/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-d357f963b0fea8b37100746ad6d1376e6226b019.js' >/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-d357f963b0fea8b37100746ad6d1376e6226b019.js
[741 ms] 
[741 ms] 
[1081 ms] Start: Run: docker exec -u root -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/vscode-ssh-auth-d357f963b0fea8b37100746ad6d1376e6226b019.sock -e REMOTE_CONTAINERS_IPC=/tmp/vscode-remote-containers-ipc-d357f963b0fea8b37100746ad6d1376e6226b019.sock 1092b2cb7af09d3f9c9648f243f2279ac7ad895e215d859be57542c9f3d87f0e git clone https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole.git /workspaces/piotr-helloworldconsole
[1207 ms] Cloning into '/workspaces/piotr-helloworldconsole'...
[2346 ms] remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier piotr-helloworldconsole.git does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole.git/' not found
```

Comment: Submitted a VS Code bug: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93473

Comment: After checking [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-open-a-git-repository-in-an-isolated-container-volume) again, I guess maybe this option for now doesn't support Azure Devops repos Url? Any update about this issue  feel free to let me know !

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT No updates and I don't see any progress on my github issue either.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing? I can clone the repo just fine from the terminal:

You use wrong Url format for your Azure Devops repos. Different from normal GitHub url, the correct Url format for Azure Devops Repos end with `ReposName` instead of `.git`.

[image]

`FtpUpload` is name of my Azure Devops repos.

So `https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole` works in your terminal while `https://eateam.visualstudio.com/Emailage%20Code/_git/piotr-helloworldconsole.git` failed with error. Remove the extra `.git` in the Url you use in VS code, and it should work.

**To reproduce the issue:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm afraid I use the (seemingly) correct URL given by the azure-devops ui, please see my update.

Comment: It seems that in one specific step VS code turn the correct url(you copied) into wrong format. The url you copy ends with repos name while the error message indicates it's using an extra .git.